# Oracle Forms many to many relationship

Tags: oracle, forms, many-to-many, relationship

I am new to Oracle Forms and PL/SQL. Here is one of many questions I have:

I have three tables: A, B as main tables and AB as my cross reference table. 
Between A and B was a many to many relationship which i transformed to two one to many relationships with the help of my cross reference table.

How can I achieve that when I have the tables in one form and I click on one record in table A that the dependent records in B are shown?

I did it with two tables in a one to many relationship with the Oracle Forms Master/Detail block relationship function, but in a many to many relationship it wont work. When I click on the record in table A, it shows the dependet records in table AB but not in table B and when I click on table B it shows the dependet records in table AB but not in table A.

Answer (score 0):

You don’t have to create a cross reference table AB. Try following steps to achieve this.
Solution 1:
•   Create a database view joining tables A and B.
•   Create a control block in Oracle Forms to place the columns to be used for your query.
•   Create a multi-record database block with new DB view as base table
•   Now you can query using the key column in either A or B table
Solution 2:
•   Create a control block in Oracle Forms to place the columns to be used for your query.
•   Create two multi-record database blocks with A and B tables as base tables respectively.
•   Toggle the views (canvases) when you press Submit button in control block after entering key values for respective query.